# Why can't I open this XML in SAXParser?

Tags: java, xml, debugging, exception, parsing

```
public static void parseit(String thexml){
     SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
     SAXParser saxParser;

    try {
        saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            }
            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException {

            }           
            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

            }               
         };      
        saxParser.parse(thexml, handler);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("e", "e", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
}
```

This is my code. (many thanks to these guys: [Can someone help me with this JAVA SAXParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250450/can-someone-help-me-with-this-java-saxparser))

The problem is, I'm always getting into the **IOException e**. The message is this:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't open....and then my XML file.
```

My XML file is this, and it's a **String**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <person>
        <first_name>Mike</first_name>
    </person>
</result>
```

Why can't it read my XML String?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `parse` method you call expects an URI to the XML file to read.

What you might want to do instead is to create an [`InputSource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) from a [`StringReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) like this:

```
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(thexml));
saxParser.parse(source, handler);
```

Answer (score 3):

SAXParser's [parse](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler%29) method expects a file name or URI as first argument, not an XML file read into a string.